# How can I warp a real data into angularjs 1 promise?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I have a page on AngularJS 1.5. It has a service layer to handle data loading by using promise.

The controller will call the service to get data like this:

```
var loadClients = programSelectorService.loadClients();
var loadYears = programSelectorService.loadYears();
$q.all([loadClients, loadYears ]).then(
    function(values) {
        handleClients(values[0]);
        handleYears(values[1]);
    },
    function(err) {
        dataModel.loadingError = err;
        dataModel.loadingClient = false;
        dataModel.loadingYear = false;
    }
);
```

It works perfectly until I add a cache service to it. The cache service directly gets real data without API call.

So I changed the service code like this in `loadClients()`:

```
var data = VCache.get(endPoint);
if(data) {
    deferred.resolve(data);   // line X
    // return data;           // line Y
    return deferred;
}
```

But neither Line X nor line Y works. For line X, the caller will find `values[0]` is a promise rather than the actual data. For line Y, the caller will find `values[0]` is `null`.

I don't want to change the caller code. So my question is: How can I warp a real data into AngularJS 1 promise?

Justin

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show how you create the `deferred` variable?

Comment: Well `return deferred;` is not right as you should not return promises from a promise callback. You should return the data like you did, the fact that it is `null` could be because the service returns that or your `deferred` object is doing pre-processing to the data making it null before returninig it. Please include your whole `loadClients` code for us to see how you are handling `deferred`.

Comment: Please post the complete code of your `loadClients` functions, with and without caching.

Comment: This is how I create deferred:  var deferred = $q.defer();

Answer (score 1):

In your case you have the data up front, so assuming you are using the `$q` service you can just return a resolved promise:

```
var data = VCache.get(endPoint);

return $q.resolve(data);
```

The general pattern is like this:

```
var deferred = $q.defer();

// Some async operation that completes later

setTimeout(function() {
    var data = VCache.get(endPoint);

    deferred.resolve(data);
}, 1000);

// Return the promise immediately

return deferred.promise;
```

Comment: Your suggestion works:  return $q.resolve(data); Thanks a lot!